# What resistor do I need?

Tags: led, batteries, resistors

I have an LED that is rated for 34V at 3A and about 100 watts. I am trying to figure out what power resistor I need with a 36V battery supply. I think I need a 10W 1 Ohm resistor but I am not sure. Did I calculate that correctly or will that resistor burn out?

Edit: Would a LM2596 DC to DC Buck Converter work instead of a resistor(s)?

Comment: Datasheet/product page?

Comment: Are you sure this is a single Led and not some kind of spotlight (multiple LEDs with internal regulator)? If it is a single Led you would need to know the forward voltage under load conditions to determine the resistance needed. But I‘m pretty sure that this is no single Led.

Comment: Specification:
Quantity: 1 piece / Pack
Brand: Chanzon
Power: 100W Watt (Max)
Emitting Color: White (6000K-6500K)
Recommended Current: 3000mA
Forward Voltage: 30-34V
Luminous Flux: 8000-9000LM
Emitting Angle: 120-140 degree
With Double Golden Wire (99.99%) and Copper Frame

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should calculate the resistance based on the minimum forward voltage:

$$\frac{36\ {\rm V}-30\ {\rm V}}{R}=3\ {\rm A}$$

So really you want about 2 ohms, not 1 ohm.

And the power consumed by the resistor will be \$I^2R = 3^2\times 2\$, or 18 W. So 10 W is not adequate. You might use, for example, three 6.2 ohm 10 W resistors in parallel here.

As another answer says, to deal with the Vf variation without changing the LED brightness, a constant current source is better than a resistive current limiter.

Comment: +1 for solid math and a correct answer. OP: consider how you will dissipate the 18W of heat generated by the resistor(s), as well as effects that different failures of parallel resistors would have.

Comment: Would a LM2596 DC to DC Buck Converter work instead of a resistor(s)?